# call xslt template with parameter

Tags: xslt

I have this xslt:

```
  <xsl:template name="dumpDebugData">
    <xsl:param name="elementToDump" />
    <xsl:for-each select="$elementToDump/@*">
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>    <!-- newline char -->
      <xsl:value-of select="name()" /> : <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

i want to display every element (as in name/value), how do i call this template?

Comment: *Sorry to add an answer when I just wanted to comment. This is due to StackOverflow limitations based upon score...* @samjudson: Which problems were there in the original ? Can you explain, please, the issues you fixed ? Thanks

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Since the template expects a node set, you must do:

```
<xsl:call-template name="dumpDebugData">
  <xsl:with-param name="elementToDump" select="some/xpath" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

Answer (score 14):

Try something like this:

```
<xsl:call-template name="dumpDebugData">
    <xsl:with-param name="elementToDump">foo</xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
```

Comment: because is passes a string into the template, not a nodeset?

Comment: Very true, but it was just a simple example of how to call a template with parameters.

Answer (score 7):

The original answer does not use the parameter.  It only works if the paramater = the current element.  This takes the parameter into account.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output indent="yes" />
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
   <xsl:template match="element()">
      <xsl:call-template name="dumpDebugData">
         <xsl:with-param name="elementToDump" select="." />
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template name="dumpDebugData">
      <xsl:param name="elementToDump" />
      Node:
      <xsl:value-of select="name($elementToDump)" />
      :
      <xsl:value-of select="text($elementToDump)" />
      <xsl:for-each select="$elementToDump/@*">
         Attribute:
         <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
         :
         <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of issues in your original XSLT, so I worked through it and got you the following code which does what you want I believe:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output indent="yes" />
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
   <xsl:template match="element()">
      <xsl:call-template name="dumpDebugData">
         <xsl:with-param name="elementToDump" select="." />
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template name="dumpDebugData">
      <xsl:param name="elementToDump" />
      Node:
      <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
      :
      <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
      <xsl:for-each select="attribute::*">
         Attribute:
         <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
         :
         <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```