# How to apply or import an XSLT template based on parametre

Tags: xml, templates, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am looking to find out how to apply a template to an XML file, based on a parameter in the XML file.

The XML file has the following format :

```
<workfile>  
    <query>  
        <some-info-1/>  
        <some-info-2/>  
        <some-info-3/>  
        <some-info-4/>  
        <some-info-5/>  
        <some-info-6/>  
        <some-info-7/>  
        <parameter name="hours-min" value="7" />  
        <parameter name="hours-max" value="9" />  
        <parameter name="output-type" value="type-1" />  
    </query>  
</workfile>
```

The XML file is generated by another program, and requires a specific output format depending on the value of the parameter "output-type". This parameter can occur several times, if the results have to be generated for several outputs at the same time, so will require a `for-each` loop.

**Edit** Here is an example with several output-type parameters :

```
<workfile>  
    <query>  
        <some-info-1/>  
        <some-info-2/>  
        <some-info-3/>  
        <parameter name="hours-min" value="7" />  
        <parameter name="hours-max" value="9" />  
        <parameter name="output-type" value="type-1" />  
        <parameter name="output-type" value="type-2" />  
        <parameter name="output-type" value="type-3" />  
    </query>  
</workfile>
```

I would like to create a main template file `generate-main.xsl` and, in the file, import/include the other template files (generate-type-1.xsl, generate-type-2.xsl, and so on). Each of these templates will have to work from the root node (`/`). But I am having issues conceiving how to do this.

This is the `generate-main.xsl`base I wrote :

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <results>
        <xsl:for-each select="/workfile/query/parameter[@name='output-type']">
            <xsl:variable name="outputType" select="./@value" />
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$outputType='type-1'">
                    <xsl:call-template name="type-1" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$outputType='type-2'">
                    <xsl:call-template name="type-2" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$outputType='type-3'">
                    <xsl:call-template name="type-3" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$outputType='type-4'">
                    <xsl:call-template name="type-4" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$outputType='type-5'">
                    <xsl:call-template name="type-5" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </results>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="type-1">
        <!-- TO DO -->
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="type-2">
        <!-- TO DO -->
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="type-3">
        <!-- TO DO -->
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="type-4">
        <!-- TO DO -->
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="type-5">
        <!-- TO DO -->
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I did do research on this. For example, Dimitre Novatchev answered this question for when templates are in the same XSL file ([Applying different XSLT template depending on a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587197/applying-different-xslt-template-depending-on-a-parameter)), but I didn't find how I would be able to do so with imported XSL files that work from the root node.

So my questions are :
1) Is it possible to include or import templates into a main XSL file and only call one depending on a parameter (for example, by playing the include inside the called template?)
2) Is it still possible if all included templates work with the root node (and, I would assume, start with `<template match="/">`)?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Anton Harris

Comment: I also found how to call a template with a parameter, to specify the root node [(call xslt template with parameter)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957029/call-xslt-template-with-parameter), but I don't see how to apply this to called templates.

Comment: Could you provide an example of input with more than one "parameter"? And specify what the expected output in such case is? Note that usually a "parameter" means something supplied to the stylesheet at runtime by the calling routine - not something included in the processed XML as part of the data.

Comment: The parameter is literally a tag, `<parameter>`. The other parameters do not impact which template to call. Other parameters include minimum work hours (`<parameter name="min-hours" value="7" />`), maximum work hours (`<parameter name="max-hours" value="9" />`), and others. I've edited the code to include other parameters in the example.

Comment: I meant an example with multiple "output-type" parameters.

Comment: I have edited in an exemple XML with multiple output-type parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include and import work at compile time, when there is no source document available, so you can't import or include things based on what you find in the data (unless you want to get into dynamic stylesheet generation, which I doubt is appropriate here).

It's not clear to me why you can't solve the problem using the standard apply-templates mechanism. Replace this stuff:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/workfile/query/parameter[@name='output-type']">
            <xsl:variable name="outputType" select="./@value" />
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$outputType='type-1'">
                    <xsl:call-template name="type-1" />
                </xsl:when>

<xsl:template name="type-1">
    <!-- TO DO -->
</xsl:template>
```

(which is very un-XSLT-like, and verbose)

with

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/workfile/query/parameter[@name='output-type']"/>

<xsl:template match="parameter[@name='output-type'][@value='type1']">
<!-- TO DO -->
</xsl:template>
```

etc.

Why would you want all included templates to start at the root node?

Comment: Thank you for answering. This XSLT file is the final step of a project, which includes XSLT files applied to a starting XML file, and calls to web services. The results (specified by parameter 'output-type') depend on both the starting query information (eg., sum of hours may be out of range, with the max and min hours stipulated in <query> node, and require generation of error messages), as well as information fetched before the execution of this XSLT file. Hope this answers your question. This is why called templated require access to root node.

Comment: Also, I'm looking to include/import because we are two people working on the project, and it's to avoid a lot of copy/paste-ing of code. (Seperate comment because previous comment would be too long otherwise.)

Comment: After looking over the code and thinking about the answer to your last question, I believe that I have been over-complexifying what I wanted to do. So I will be cutting down on bloat, and should be able to reach the result. I will be marking this answer as correct, since it led me to what I wanted.

Answer (score -1):

I think there are two questions here:

1. Can you do what you are trying to do?
2. Should you do what you are trying do?

The answer to the first question is definitely yes. You can *include* other stylesheets in your main stylesheet and call their templates in the same manner as templates in the main stylesheet. And each template can select whatever it needs to select - including starting from the root, if necessary.

Note that the included stylesheets are included always - with no regard to what happens at runtime. You can decide  whether to *use* them, according to the input; but they will always be there.

The answer to the second question is more difficult, because the description is too abstract. I suspect you could get more mileage out of a single "output" template, called several times - each time with a different parameter. Then use the `choose` element *inside* the template to produce the appropriate output.

Comment: Could you tell me how the description is too abstract, so that I can provide additional details?

Comment: @AntonH: I mean we don't know what the different templates do. We don't even know what kind of data is under "some-info". This is a matter of strategy, and it's hard to say what the best strategy is when we don't really know what we are dealing with.

Comment: I don't see how knowing what the templates do, nor specifying what other information is in the <query> node, would help, since the templates *by themselves* work, and the other information (<some-info>) isn't taken into account for my question. My question is concerning the calling of templates included in other files.